# Creating batch file launching .phar with alias

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, command-line-interface

I'm currently experimenting with **WP-CLI** (http://wp-cli.org) - I have finally managed to get it to run on my basic command line by downloading/moving it to a *PATH* variable directory (i.e C:\xampp\php) and then updating my *PATHSPEC* to include .PHAR.

I have renamed the original file from wp-cli.phar to wp.phar in order to be able to reference it as wp in my cmd.exe.

Prior to this method I installed wp-cli using CURL and chmod in my Git Bash installation then renaming the file to wp (without an extension) and adding the path containing file to the PATH variable. This caused the .PHAR file to work in Git Bash but not to work on the command line.

**MY ISSUE:**

Whenever I try to use my wp.phar in the native CLI I get a php error report - it does recognise the command  and does show a list of suggestions (which is usually given when syntax is incomplete or incorrect).

[image: command line screenshot showing my output]

***How do I even start to figure this out?***

1 - I've attempted to look for a git batch file in my Git Bash directory to see if I can find a dependency I'm missing but no dice.

2 - My Git Bash is now not recognizing the `wp` command and I now need to refer to `wp.phar`and then add any sub-commands/arguments after. However using the Git Bash CLI `wp.phar` doesn't cause errors

Comment: So what is the contents of the `wp` file you're invoking? Is it the original `wp.phar` or you created a `.bat`-file wrapper?

Comment: Original .phar file. I'm basically attempting to create equivalent to sudo chmod +x wp-cli.phar then sudo mv to usr/bin/wp. This is supposed to then setup the original wp-cli.phar as a Global on the terminal (under Linux).

Answer (score 2):

After a few months I found a solution.

1. Make sure that your **PHP root folder path** and the folder path containing your phar files are added to the Windows PATH Environment Variable (to allow us to just use the filename to refer to them).
2. CMD Line Options (Run as Administrator):

   - `assoc .php=phpfile` and `assoc .phar=pharfile`

[image: How to associate .php files on windows with a global variable name]

- Next is adding the program that opens this file. Adding an ftype command allows us to open .php/.phar files without using the `php`.

  `ftype pharfile=php.exe %1 %*` (The %1 is a placeholder for the file called and %* refers to any other arguments that many be input).

[image: How to get php to open all files with .php by default]

**FINALLY**

The key issue was getting the .phar scripts to execute in the command line as windows ends up trying to open these files in it's Open With Dialog

[image: Open with Dialog Issue which occurs when trying to open .phar file without GUI application.]

So what I did was wrap my .phar in a batch file with this command (in the same folder as the phar

`echo php "%~dp0wp-cli.phar" %* > [name of file].cmd`

I then run this file as [name of file] with any arguments and it works as usual.